# Why can’t one use the verb 'to stay' in “Two yoghurts stayed in the fridge”?

Tags: difference, verbs

"After he finished eating, only two yoghurts **stayed** in the fridge".
Why should I use 'were left' instead of 'stayed' in this sentence?

Comment: Because yoghurts don't have a brain, and therefore can't decide to stay in a fridge.

Comment: I don't know... I've had yogurts in my fridge that were close to evolving legs...

Comment: @JamesK - If I bring home a multipack of assorted yogurts, the apricot ones always stay in the fridge until my sister comes to visit. I could have used 'remain', and in the OP's example, that's the verb I'd use, in the past tense,

Comment: It's not grammatically wrong, but it's not idiomatic.

Comment: It's not even wrong: "two yoghurts were brought out for dessert, two stayed in the fridge for the next day".

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd But with the first clause in the OP's question, that doesn't work and *is* wrong. Or at least it's a childish way of phrasing it - it's perfectly comprehensible, but it's a bit wrong enough that only a child would say it like that.

Comment: @Graham It's unclear which takes precedence: the subject line or the question body... I was treating the body as an example. I'll certainly agree that it's an /odd/- perhaps /quaint/- way of putting it, but usage like "that can stay there until later" is- IMO- by no means uncommon.

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd The general SE rule is that the question body always has to take precedence, because the question body has space for detail and context which you can't necessarily squeeze into a subject line. :)  If the subject line was grossly incorrect, of course you'd hope the author (or a mod) would fix it, but in this case it's really just missing the context of the full sentence.  I agree with you that in other contexts (like your example), "stayed" would be fine.

Comment: @Graham isn't "it's comprehensible and there's no real rule against it, but no native speaker would say it that way" basically what "not idiomatic" means?

Comment: As a native speaker of English, I would not think twice about saying it that way. There is nothing unidiomatic about the sentence, and that so many people here appear to think that there is is baffling.

Comment: What are the yogurts doing in the fridge? Sitting there while you eat their colleagues, waiting till dessert time, or remaining there permanently, or something in between? It's not helpful to ask "Can I say 'X'?" without saying why you want to say it or what you think it will mean.

Comment: 'After he finished eating, only…' seems helpful and I suggest that in fact, it's just confusing.

I didn't go for Billy's abrupt style but I do think his Comment was broadly correct. 'Stay' is either a choice or an order, and neither could apply to anything insensible.

Someone might provide grammatical justification but still, 'yoghurts stayed' would never be idiomatic.

In that sense, 'remained' or 'were left' or even 'languished' would be greatly preferable.

Answer (score 23):

**to stay in the fridge** has various meanings:

> This soft cheese has to stay in the fridge or it will go bad.

stay = be kept; remain

> Nobody in the house likes this flavor very much. These sodas stay in the fridge the longest.

stay = sit untouched ; that is, are not removed from the fridge to be consumed

Some people also use "stay" to mean "stay fresh" or "keep", that is, remain edible:

> Will a cured ham stay in the fridge indefinitely?

One thing "stay" does not mean is "to be left, to be the remainder":

> Since he took two beers from the six-pack, four beers now stay in the fridge.<sup>unidiomatic</sup>

Comment: There is nothing unidiomatic about the sentence you label "unidiomatic" at the end of your answer. It is just as idiomatic as your first and second sentences, and indeed the sense of the word "stay" being used is the same one. Whether the things staying are the remainder from some collection of things is irrelevant.

Comment: @Hammerite to me the first definition is much more emphasising the "be kept" part. I would say that for general purposes the idiomatic expression for the last one would be to replace "stay" with "remain" or "are left"; however if you for some reason wanted to emphasise the location where the beers are as opposed to the fact that they're still there, stay would work to my ears. You could colloquially replace "stay" with "live" and have the same meaning and connotations to my ears (though using "live" for inanimate objects is quite informal/cutsey). British English speaker.

Comment: In fact another interpretation just occurred to me, which is that you wish to keep four beers in the fridge at all times. The last sentence would also work for that. It wouldn't necessarily be those four beers; the idea being that when someone takes one out they should replace it with a new one.

Comment: @Hammerite I thought it was clear that I meant that sentence would not be an idiomatic way of saying "four beers remain" or "there are four beers *left* in the fridge".  At least in AmE the word "stay" does not have that sense.  "left" conveys the idea that some have been removed; "stay" does not convey that idea.

Comment: @TimR Your first example says *stay* can mean *remain*,  your second says *sit untouched*, but both of those fit OP's sentence. perfectly. I suspect the real issue is the *After he finished eating* clause. While he was fishing the other ones out of the fridge those two stayed in the fridge. But it doesn't make sense to say they staid in the fridge *after* he was fishing the others out! (When we use *stay* with this meaning it has to contrast with some expectation that they might be being moved/move for some other reason).

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore.  I don't mean to suggest that the various meanings I've listed all apply to OP's sentence if it is left "as is". For exactly the reason you cite: "After he finished eating",  the "sit untouched" meaning and OP's sentence are not amenable.  And I understood from OP's phrasing, "After he finished.... only two" that OP wanted to express the idea of remainder: "were left".

Comment: @TimR I think the problem is this: *stay* is used when there is an expectation that something will move/might have movede: "I thought he was going to eat those yoghurts, but they stayed in the fridge". But in OP's sentence the *only* strongly indicates that the expectation was that even less yoghurts would have been taken, not that those two would have gone as well And after he's finished eating there's *no* expectation that any yoghurts would move!

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore.  OP hasn't really clarified what they're hoping to say. So I''ve given several senses, and I stand by my statement that we don't use "stay" to express the notion of remainder. If the notion of remainder is not what OP was hoping to express, perhaps OP can clarify.

Answer (score 9):

You can say something “stays” in a specific place.

> Jams, mayo, pickles, chutney and sauces e.g. mustard, apple sauce go in the fridge once opened. Marmite, honey, ketchup, soy sauce, peanut butter, *Lea and Perrins* **[stay in the cupboard](https://www.mumsnet.com/talk/housekeeping/1028978-Do-you-store-condiments-in-the-fridge)**. Unopened mayo, jam and chutney **stay** either **in the cupboard** or under the stairs - our secret chutney stash!!

Here's another example taken from the *Queen Mary University of London* website

> [Tins can stay in the cupboard for months](https://residentiallife.qmul.ac.uk/the-essentials-for-your-first-food-shop_123777) so get them all stocked up. The most important ones to have are chopped tomatoes, sweetcorn, tuna and baked beans, so get plenty.

Maybe it's different for fridges? No, not really. Fresh milk, animal or human, is usually kept in a fridge otherwise it spoils. The following excerpt is taken from  [Parenting.SE,](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/a/18264/11750)

> The longer the breast milk stays above refrigerated temperatures, the less time it will be viable in the fridge. Guidelines say that milk in the fridge can last 5-8 days, but that time will be considerably less if the milk isn't properly placed in the refrigerator immediately after pumping. Conversely, **the longer the milk stays in the fridge**, the less time it will be viable at room temperature.

**The correct answer** in the OP's example is “were left” because it focuses our attention on the nearly empty fridge. There were no other provisions apart from the two yoghurt pots.

> "After he finished eating, **only two yoghurts were left** in the fridge".

Only two yoghurts remained in the fridge after the man had eaten almost everything.

*Cambridge Dictionary* says about **[be left](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/be-left)**

> If something or someone is left, they remain after the rest of the things or people have gone or been used:
>
> - Are there any cookies left?
> - There's some food left over from the party.
> - Of the original group of men, only three were left.

Comment: Thank you, great answer. For me, no matter how empty or full the fridge is, "were left" is the idiomatic choice in that sentence.

Comment: Someone coming to English only recently would never notice, but using *yoghurt* as a plural count noun to mean several **pre-packaged containers** of it is a recent phenomenon. We've had yoghurt for more than four centuries, but the OED says that using it to mean a little plastic container of it is much more recent, their earliest citation dating only to 1968. This now happens to any number of former mass nouns whenever they've been packaged up into little throw-away, single-serving containers: *salts, peppers, honeys, mustards,  mayos, milks, creams, sugars, waters, wines, beers*.

Comment: Maybe mention that "were left" here is the ordinary past tense of "to leave": I will leave the room with one yogurt, I left the room with one yogurt, I left the other two yogurts in the room, the other yogurts were left in the room. I took out one yogurt and the other two were left.

Comment: Wouldn't it be "after the man had eaten..."?

Comment: @screwtop that would also work, but simple past works perfectly well because the events (1. eating 2. only food left) happen consecutively.

Comment: @screwtop I've only just seen the error in my writing! You were pointing out the non-standard "after he had ate". Will fix it immediately. Thank you :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yes, that was the one. :) No problem, and nice answer.

Comment: @MJD: Probably because it's not an ordinary past tense: it's passive voice.  Ordinary past: *I took one yogurt and left the other two.*  Passive: *One yogurt was taken and the other two were left.*

Answer (score 5):

Because "stay," in this usage, implies doing something on purpose. The yoghurts are non-sentient; they didn't choose to stay. Even though definition 3 in [this entry](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stay) defines "stay" as a synonym for "remain," one big difference is that remain *can* be used this way. In [the entry for "remain"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/remain), we find definition 2:

> to stay in the same place or with the same person or group; especially : to stay behind

... but there's also definition 1a:

> to be a part not destroyed, taken, or used up: *only a few ruins remain*

Definition 2 has the same "stay on purpose" meaning as "stay," but 1a has the "left behind" meaning that we could use for things that didn't make a choice.

Comment: To sum up, a teacher can reasonably mark it wrong, while the casual speaker can use *stayed* freely, metaphorically, and understandably.

Comment: "*The books* [**stay in the cupboard**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22stay+in+the+cupboard%22&sca_esv=584400697&sxsrf=AM9HkKmUm8XqPSUbMzkcMJ3GBxiqQRP_Ow%3A1700604579679&ei=oypdZciOKfaLxc8PvMGkyAQ&ved=0ahUKEwiI7P_ejdaCAxX2RfEDHbwgCUkQ4dUDCBE&uact=5&oq=%22stay+in+the+cupboard%22&gs_lp=Egxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAiFiJzdGF5IGluIHRoZSBjdXBib2FyZCIyCBAAGBYYHhgPMgYQABgWGB4yCBAAGBYYHhgPMgsQABiABBiKBRiGAzILEAAYgAQYigUYhgNI6yNQiQtY0R5wAXgBkAEAmAFfoAGYAqoBATO4AQPIAQD4AQHCAgoQABhHGNYEGLADwgIEECMYJ-IDBBgAIEGIBgGQBgg&sclient=gws-wiz-serp)"?

Comment: @Mari-LouA I considered mentioning that but didn't want to confuse things. That one's not describing a state but ordering one; short for "the books [should] stay in the cupboard." You still wouldn't say "the books stayed in the cupboard."

Comment: "*The toys* ***stayed*** *all night* ***in Billy's box***" sounds fine to me :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA Well... maybe in the movie *Toy Story*, in which they're sentient... but yes, I can imagine saying "Sometimes leftovers stay in my fridge for months." But I still can't imagine saying "after I took one out, two yoghurts stayed in the fridge." I'm not sure, but this seems to be pointing to a difference in usage based on including a time frame. There's "stay" as "take residence in for a while," and then there's what the OP is trying for, "stay" as in "remain behind."

Comment: The correct answer is "were left" because there was no other food in the fridge. As for the Toy Story analogy,  a wholly non-sentient example could be: *The cake stayed in the oven too long and became bone dry* (“was left” also works though)

Comment: "the books stay in the cupboard" strikes me as a "Dad -like" aggressively implicit command.

Comment: Food can spoil if it _stays_ on the counter for too long.

Comment: @Mari-LouA There could be other food, just only two containers of yogurt. "There's only one roll of toilet paper left in the cabinet." means we're almost out of toilet paper, not that the first aid kit that's in the cabinet has gone missing. The other way you'd need to say "There was _nothing but_ two yogurts left in the fridge."

Comment: This answer is wrong, and bizarre. The verb "stay" does not in fact imply that the thing staying has a mind of its own.

Answer (score 0):

You can, in fact use the verb "stay" the way it is used in your example sentence. There is nothing wrong with that sentence.

Answer (score 0):

"Only two yoghurts stayed in the fridge" is fine. But it means something different from what you want. It refers to the situation **after he took all but two yoghurts out of the fridge.**

However, your words "After he finished eating," shows that you're talking about the situation **after he had eaten all those yoghurts** and whatever else he had taken from the fridge. In that case, "stayed" is not idiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

"After he finished eating, only two yoghurts stayed in the fridge until the next morning".

It does not imply sentience, nothing of the sort. No decision is involved.

In this case there could be more than two yoghurts undisturbed in the fridge after he finished eating, and all but two have been removed in the following interval.  The interval is not necessary. Yoghurts can stay, yoghurts can lurk, perhaps hidden behind the broccoli or the coriander.

Stay is an abeyance. I stayed in the finest hotel. Stay your hand.  Stay here.

The yoghurts will stay in the fridge, so help me...

So turn off the Grammarly and keep the language alive.

From the answer that followed, the two yoghurts stayed in the fridge from noon until evening.

Answer (score 0):

I see a comparison between 'to stay' and 'to 'live' as verbs used with inanimate things as sentence subjects...

When, as a child (several decades ago), I first heard someone say, "The knife lives in that drawer", I thought it very funny. Knives are inanimate and don't *live* anywhere! I think that this use of "live(s) has since become much more common – in the UK at least – and I have long since stopped laughing when I hear it.

The case with 'stay(s) is, I believe, rather similar, though never as marked. 'Stay(s)' is *primarily* said of creatures with consciousness, but I didn't bat an eyelid to read of yoghurts staying in the fridge. I would consider it rather pedantic to object to this usage.